# Encrypt nullmailer/ssmtp using PGP?

Tags: smtp, pgp

I need smtp for mdadm and other alerts but i don't want to maintain my own postifix/dovecot is there an easy way to automatically encrypt mail with PGP and send it out using an external SMTP and then retrieve and decode it using thunderbird?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have full automation steps for you, but this is how you would manually send one encrypted PGP email on Debian/Ubuntu with [nullmailer](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/nullmailer/nullmailer.7.en.html).

First install [nullmailer](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/nullmailer) with `sudo apt install --yes nullmailer`.

Make sure you configure a working SMTP server in `/etc/nullmailer/remotes`. I for example have a line like this: `mail.gandi.net smtp --auth-login --port=587 --starttls --user=me@example.com --pass=x1x2x3x4x5x6`.

To construct the actual email, write the text in a file `example.txt` and then to sign and encrypt the file execute `gpg --recipient AEA84EDCF01AD86C4701C85C63113AE866587D0A --trust-model=always --armor --sign --encrypt example.txt`. In this example the recipient key is for Werner Koch, the author of GnuPG. Naturally you need to replace this with a public key of your particular intended recipient.

If you don't want to sign the message, simply omit the `--sign`. If you *don't want to encrypt* but simply sign the message, use `gpg --clear-sign example.txt`.

These commands will create a file called `example.txt.asc`. You can see that it is now encrypted:

```
$ head --lines=5 example.txt.asc
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

hJ4DK5mfqc4EaxsSAwMEa0dD7d8SkCmgid3d2e1CGKGAV+rvlQoX0urYZfyaQta+
2+A13jXxJwgjK6+KZgmtizelapO1lklV0NEQFp/K1sDzkqS6QGpRDJJ6BFLh8cqC
B8+LaWH7b6bgH0TQgzseMM24wgGMcf6c6HNoEQPgagLRe3waj7Yxgfz0a7fvRuSs
...
```

Next open this file in a text editor, and prepend it with the mandatory minimal email headers:

```
$ nano example.txt.asc
From: me@example.com
Cc: me@example.com
To: somebody@example.com
Subject: This is an encrypted demo email

-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

hJ4DK5mfqc4EaxsSAwMEa0dD7d8SkCmgid3d2e1CGKGAV+rvlQoX0urYZfyaQta+
2+A13jXxJwgjK6+KZgmtizelapO1lklV0NEQFp/K1sDzkqS6QGpRDJJ6BFLh8cqC
B8+LaWH7b6bgH0TQgzseMM24wgGMcf6c6HNoEQPgagLRe3waj7Yxgfz0a7fvRuSs
...
```

Once you have this, you can test what Nullmailer would do it using the `-n` parameter:

```
$ cat example.txt.asc | nullmailer-inject -n
From: me@example.com
Cc: me@example.com
To: somebody@example.com
Subject: This is an encrypted demo email
Date: Thu, 28 Dec 2023 23:23:23 +0000
Message-Id: <1703771097.123.123.nullmailer@demo>

-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

hJ4DK5mfqc4EaxsSAwMEa0dD7d8SkCmgid3d2e1CGKGAV+rvlQoX0urYZfyaQta+
2+A13jXxJwgjK6+KZgmtizelapO1lklV0NEQFp/K1sDzkqS6QGpRDJJ6BFLh8cqC
B8+LaWH7b6bgH0TQgzseMM24wgGMcf6c6HNoEQPgagLRe3waj7Yxgfz0a7fvRuSs
...
```

If everything looks good, repeat the same but use parameter `-h` to send it for real:

```
$ cat example.txt.asc | nullmailer-inject -h
$
```

Nullmailer does not give any result/feedback here. All you can do at this point is to look at the raw queues to see if there are any messages undelivered with `sudo find /var/spool/nullmailer/ -type f`. After some time you should see a copy arrive in your own email if you had the `Cc` line.